# English dictionary IPA or/and sound

Tags: words

I was wondering if one can look-up English words in Emacs from an English dictionary that includes IPA or plays a sound. I am using define-word.el package, which is very good but doesn't have IPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or plays a sound

Something *in that spirit* will, at least, give you the *reading of the word* you're looking for, assuming you have something like [espeak](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech#Espeak) installed on your computer

`(defun my-read-word-at-point ()
  "READ CURRENT WORD."
  (interactive)
  (message "reading: %s" (thing-at-point 'word 'no-properties))
  (shell-command (format "espeak -v en-us %s" (thing-at-point 'word 'no-properties))))`

Comment: Thanks. Never knew about espeak - sounds a bit weird but I think will do the job for now.

Comment: I wrote a bash script to parse HTML page from Oxford Online Dictionary for a word and play it with `mplayer` as you suggested above and render the IPA in the minibuffer.

Comment: @A.Blizzard Really nice.You may also want to read this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39387/asynchronous-version-of-shell-command-on-region/39393#39393), just in case o/