# Asynchronous version of shell-command-on-region?

Tags: region, process, shell-command, subprocess, async

I have a problem which is very similar to [this one.](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/Spawning-autonomous-shell-commands-td265362.html) I have some text that I'd like to listen to with macOS's [`say`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html) utility. Unfortunately, Emacs locks up when I use `shell-command-on-region` because it is not asynchronous. In other words, Emacs waits for the shell process to finish before it does anything else. This is highly inconvenient and would be resolved with an asynchronous version of `shell-command-on-region`. Yet, it seems that no such function exists despite there being other asynchronous alternatives to `shell-` commands. Does anyone know of a simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the answers suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766550/how-do-i-execute-a-shell-command-in-background) not satisfying?

Comment: @Nsukami_ That post deals specifically with `shell-command`. I'm looking for answers pertaining to `shell-command-on-region`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something *in this spirit* should do the trick. I tried it with `espeak` under Ubuntu; I guess it would work with `say` as well.

```el
(defun my-read-words-on-region ()
  "Send the region to `espeak'."
  (interactive)
  (start-process "espeak-process" "espeak-buffer" "espeak" "-v" "en-us")
  (process-send-region "espeak-process" (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

**EDIT:**

The previous function assume the process name is unique, which it may not be if you happen to call the function twice, so, following [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs)'s suggestion, a better approach would be:

```el
(defun my-read-words-on-region-2 ()
  "Send the region to `espeak'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((proc (start-process "espeak-process" "espeak-buffer" "espeak" "-v" "en-us")))
    (process-send-region proc (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

Comment: I suggest `(let ((proc (start-process ...))) (process-send-region proc ...))`, otherwise you assume the process name is unique, which it may not be if you happen to call the function  twice...

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for the suggestion o/

Comment: Thanks! The second function seems to work fine and I'll probably bind it to a key for easy use. Of course, I replaced `espeak` with `say` and the arguments for it that I desired.